# I can't copy my file into my 2GB memory stick

Tags: macos, usb, disk-space

I have a Verbatim 2 GB memory stick that I need to copy an MP4 movie onto to post off. The movie is 544.5 MB. As far as I can see, all other files have been removed from the USB stick, but it says there is not enough space!

**Note:** I am using OS X 10.9

Comment: Have you emptied your Trash?

Comment: Next to the drive’s desktop icon, what’s the reported amount of free space?

Comment: Wow. Ok it says 166MB available (which makes sense as to why I can't copy the movie) but there are no discernible files. How can I reboot/format it so its clean again?

Comment: Mark - Just trying that now.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Since your idea was the answer, please post it as an answer so the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Try emptying your Trash - as files in there still take up space.